# What does "blow a story" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Ben Horowitz [tweets](https://twitter.com/bhorowitz/status/442295611325702144), "These annotations have completely convinced me that Newsweek blew the story."

Does this mean that Newsweek was correct, and was the first to the scoop? Or does this mean that Newsweek blew it, got the story wrong?

Comment: Most likely the second, since that's a far more common usage than a possible shortening of *"blew [the lid on] the story"*, which is the only other credible reading I can see. But I'd have thought the intended meaning should be obvious *in context*. If you're asking about that single tweet, surely the issue must interest you enough to *know* that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Blow the lid off a story = good (first to report)
- Blow a story = bad (get the facts or perspective wrong)

I leave the puerile wisecracks for the comments.